# Alternative to HttpConfigurationExtensions.BindParameter in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core

I'm looking for an alternative in ASP .NET core to the `HttpConfigurationExtensions.BindParameter` method from .NET framework MVC.

I'm trying to create a model binder for an enum I have. 
I would like to have different behaviour than the default one.

In the .net framework I would have done this.

```cs
config.BindParameter(typeof(MyEnum), new MyEnumBinder());
```

I could have then used that enum inside my request object class. Like this.

```cs
public class MyRequestObject 
{
    public string ExampleProp { get; set; }
    public MyEnum ExampleEnum { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do the same in ASP .Net core?

I've had a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2 and tried to implement it. Unfortunately if I use a `ModelBinderProvider`, it only triggers for the `MyRequestObject` type and not for the `MyEnum` so I can't target just the `MyEnum` type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use JsonConverter instead model binder?

Check this out:

```
public enum ElapsedTime
    {
        Unknown = 1,
        SomeSeconds = 2,
        LessThanTenMinutes = 3,
        LessThanThirtyMinutes = 4,
        LessThanAnHour = 5,
        MoreThanAnHour = 6
    }
```

The JsonConverter implemnetation:

```
public class ElapsedTimeJsonConverter : JsonConverter<ElapsedTime>
    {
        public override ElapsedTime ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, ElapsedTime existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(reader.ReadAsString(), out var date))
                return ElapsedTime.Unknown;

            var elapsedTime = default(ElapsedTime);
            var timeDifference = date.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes;

            if (timeDifference < 1)
            {
                elapsedTime = ElapsedTime.SomeSeconds;
            }
            else if (timeDifference >= 1 && timeDifference < 10)
            {
                elapsedTime = ElapsedTime.LessThanTenMinutes;
            }
            else if (timeDifference >= 10 && timeDifference < 30)
            {
                elapsedTime = ElapsedTime.LessThanThirtyMinutes;
            }
            else if (timeDifference >= 30 && timeDifference < 60)
            {
                elapsedTime = ElapsedTime.LessThanAnHour;
            }
            else if (timeDifference >= 60)
            {
                elapsedTime = ElapsedTime.MoreThanAnHour;
            }

            return elapsedTime;

        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, ElapsedTime value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            //Only for preventing validation errors
            services.AddSingleton<IObjectModelValidator>(new NullObjectModelValidator());
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ElapsedTimeJsonConverter()));
        }
```

Comment: that is how I have currently implemented it. Unfortunately it requires having an "Unkown" or nullable state. I think have to validate in my controller validation whether the enum has a "correct" value. With Model binder I can return a nice message saying its not valid without having the logic in my controller.